# changing button text in OpenFileDialog in C#.net

Tags: .net, winforms, openfiledialog

Does anyone knows how to change text on button in OpenFileDialog in Windows.Forms in C#.NET?

Comment: IIRC you can't (even can't enherit the dialog). But what do you want to achieve? maybe there's an other solution

Comment: I use OpenFileDialog only to point a path of file. I use it to Opening and Saving files. If i would like to use SaveFileDialog to save files, I whould have to make several changes in code. I wish I could change button open to select. Can it be done with WinAPI perhaps?
Regards, Bart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this example on CodeProject: [OpenFileDialogEx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileDialogEx.aspx)

Basically, you will need to listen for the WM_ACTIVATE message from the modal dialog and then pass the window handle to System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.  From there, you can customize the dialog.

I'm not saying this is the only solution, but it looks like it will do the trick with the least amount of work from your end.