# .NET. How to hack OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog, filedialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [changing button text in OpenFileDialog in C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769792/changing-button-text-in-openfiledialog-in-c-net)

Have a good day,

Is there a way to override Open button in .NET OpenFileDialog?

I need to Change the button text and override OnClick event.

If this is not possible can I put a custom button over the Open button (but at the most top X order)?

--

BR
Murat

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769792/changing-button-text-in-openfiledialog-in-c-net ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible, but the question is what You really want to achieve by this strange behavior ?

What's wrong with standard usage of the OK button ? Where You pick the path and do what You want to.

Comment: Agree..  Messing with standard dialogs is usually not worth it IMHO

Comment: @Murat thats not true, you need to set the property Multiselect to true than you have multiselect in OpenFileDialog.

Comment: I need to scan several folders at once and use standard OpenFileDialog to allow to select multiple folders at once. When I select a few folders and click on the Open button it opens the first selected folder in the dialog. I added custom panel with custom button to this dialog. But 8 of 10 testers clicks on Open button instead of the Scan button. And begin to scan each folder one by one.

Comment: Vash, yes I can set Multiselect to true, and select multiple folders. But once I click on the Open button it opens the first select folder! So this button works only if the files are selected