# How to accomplish "Open project" dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to show *Open Directory* dialog, but I'd like to customize it so that folders which have `.project` folder inside of them are marked with a different folder icon and only those folders can be chosen.

Now I wonder if there's already a user control or a sensible way to accomplish without building your own tree view with files and write all that navigation logic on your own. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create customized open file dialog in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831432/how-to-create-customized-open-file-dialog-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of your development language, the (non-.Net) [OpenfileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx) is a built-in Windows feature and non-trivial to customize. At best, I've seen examples that hook the window and wrap it in some additional custom controls ([here](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2009/08/11/file-dialog-with-custom-constrol/)).

Looking at the [.Net 4 OpenfileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) class, it's sealed and cannot be extended.

Your best bet for accomplishing this is to build a custom dialogue, possibly by extending the same base class used by .Net 4 OpenfileDialog, [FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx).