# OpenFileDialog C# custom filter like 'ABC*.pdf'

Tags: c#, .net, filter, openfiledialog

Is it possible to specify custom filters like `'ABC*.pdf'` which means: "*Show all PDF which starts with ABC*"?

I can only specify `*.pdf`, `*.doc`, `*.*`, etc.

Thanks
Florian

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible. But you can create your own `FileDialog`

Comment: Not possible using the `Filter` property alone, but you can basically achieve this effect by using the `FileName` property, and entering `ABC*` there.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

***Updated***

Changed my solution a little after realizing the following would be better:

This is not a complete "hard filter", but making use of the `FileName` property should still cover your needs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestingFileOpenDialog
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.openFileDialog1.FileName = "pro*";
            this.openFileDialog1.Filter = "Pdf Files|*.pdf";
            this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose this might depend on which OS you are working with, but it did work in my case any way, on Windows 8.

I also realize that this does not filter out all irrelevant files "permanently", but it does at least provide an initial filter.

**Result:**
(*Without `pro*` in the FileName-field, this will show several other PDF files*).

[image]

Comment: +1 yes its working for me in windows 7. i think this is what exactly OP is looking for.

Comment: Definitely a way to achieve this. But it is possible to do it exactly like OP expected in .NET 5.0 (I don't know since which version).

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

**No**: Look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), page. The filter is not used that way. It's only for the extensions.

**Yes**: You could write your own class that extends/mimics the OpenFileDialog, have some regular expressions to do what you want, and simply run that match against all the files in the current folder (Might take some work, but if you really want it so bad, go for it :) )

Comment: Thanks, I think just a ListBox with the filtered files would be the best and fastest solution for me

Comment: There you go then ... problem solved. Mark the answer you like best as the answer, and back to coding I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in my comment:

> Unfortunately it's not possible. But you can create your own FileDialog

To create your own FileDialog, you can use the following methods:

```
  string[] Directories = Directory.GetDirectories(Path);
  string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(Path);
```

Now filter the `Files`-Array to your specifications:

```
List<string> wantedFiles = Files.ToList().Where(x => x.StartsWith("ABC"));
```

To get the file Icons, you have to use the `DLLImport` of Shell32.dll:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
```

The code provided in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872957/how-can-i-use-the-images-within-shell32-dll-in-my-c-sharp-project) should solve the problem.

A project that implements own FileDialogs written by my brother can be found here:
[Download project](http://www.abouchleih.com/wp-content/uploads/Folder_FileDialogs_Stand30092013_1703.zip)

In short, this should do the trick:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Path)
                                 .Where(x => new DirectoryInfo(x).Name.StartsWith("ABC")))
{
    //Add the string to your ListView/ListBox/...
}
```

Comment: Beware, the website(s) linked to within this answer is infected.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is straight forward : **NO**

You can set the Filters to allow only specific File Types with property `Filter` asbelow :

```
fileOpenDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
```

but filtering file names is `NOT` Possible.

You can create your own Custom `OpenFIleDialog` in that case.

See this Link for more info : [How to create customized open file dialog in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831432/how-to-create-customized-open-file-dialog-in-c-sharp)

Comment: With FileChooser in Java it is possible, so I thought there would be a way in C# as well

Comment: FileChooser is rendered by Java, OpenFileDialog by Win32 and the latter _doesn't_ support it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it again and it seems for .NET 5.0 it works just as OP expected it.

```
var fileSelector = new OpenFileDialog()
{
  Filter = "ABC Files|abc*.pdf";  
};
```

With this the FileDialog will only show .pdf files beginning with "abc".

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog myDialog. = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
myDialog..DefaultExt = ".pdf";
myDialog.Filter = "FilesIWant (ABC*.pdf)|ABC*.pdf
```

Comment: Clearly this was the first attempt of the original poster, and it does not work.