# How To Make OpenFileDialog Find A Specific Program

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I'm trying to open a certain file that I expect to be in a certain folder. If the file is not in the folder I want to show an `OpenFileDialog` so the user can browse to where the file is located and tell my program what folder to use. However, I want to limit the OpenFileDialog to only accept that specific file name that I'm looking for... say `notepad.exe`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifiying the file you want to open in file name property of openfiledialog.it will be like.

```
openFileDialog1.Filename="Note*";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Exe Files (.exe)|*.exe|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
```

If the specified default directory has the file name starting with note,then it will show that file else user can search for file in other directories.For more References,Go to this [specifying Filename in openfiledialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857824/openfiledialog-c-sharp-custom-filter-like-abc-pdf)

Comment: Hi, I have one more question. How do I make it when I press a button it grabs the file im patching and makes a copy of it renames it to blah.exe.bac

Comment: there are function for copying and renaming files in vb.net.use `file.copy(sourcefilename,destinationfilename,false)`.here the boolean argument is for enabling overwrite.