# How to change the read-only CheckBox Text property of OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, text, checkbox, custom-component, openfiledialog

I want to handle the selected file differently depending upon the OpenFileDialog Readonly check box state.

Is there any way to customize this text?

[image]

Comment: Yes, [it's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1770270/87698), but doing so is not easy and requires some in-depth knowledge of processing Windows-internal messages. If this doesn't scare you, go ahead!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create customized open file dialog in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831432/) and [Customizing OpenFileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093012/) and [Really Custom OpenFileDialog .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049822/)

Comment: [Customizing OpenFileDialog in .NET Tutorial](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c12801/Customizing-OpenFileDialog-in-NET.htm)